# Yeoman Generator in CoffeeScript - HookFor Warning

Tags: coffeescript, generator, yeoman

I'm trying to develop a custom generator for **Yeoman** using **CoffeeScript** but I'm facing a problem. When I use the `hookFor` method in the constructor of my class `Generator`, I get a warning *hookFor must be used within the constructor* when I try to init my project with Yeoman and my custom generator. Here is the code of my generator in index.coffee :

```
path = require 'path'
util = require 'util'
yeoman = require '../../../../'
module.exports = class Generator extends yeoman.generators.Base
    constructor: ->
        super()
        @directories = ['controllers', 'helpers', 'models', 'templates', 'views']
        @hookFor 'artefact:controller', args: ['App']
    deploy: ->
        @directory '.', '.'
        @mkdir path.join 'dev', directory for directory in @directories
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the error comes from **Yeoman Generators** code in the **yeoman-generators/lib/base.js** file.
Here is how I led to that conclusion :

1. The warning is caused by the variable `_running` set to `true` in `hookFor` function *(line  296)*
2. This variable is set to true in `run` function *(line 78)* and just after that, methods of the class `Generator` are iterated (line 81-137)
3. the constructor defined in CoffeeScript for the class `Generator` is called during the iteration, so `@hookFor` is called whereas `_running` is `true` : **warning!**
4. But, the constructor should not be called because a test is done during the iteration to prevent it *(line 92)* :

   ```
   if ( method.constructor === '-' )
   ```
5. However, this test, in my opinion, should be :

   ```
   if ( method === 'constructor' )
   ```

The hack does the trick. Feel free to add comment if I'm wrong.